# Showing street name in android app

Tags: android

I have code like this and I want it to show the street name of current location. I have tried many searches but can't find anything helpful. I am newbie android developer, could somebody help me to create it?

```
package yakosito.com.policija;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Map extends Activity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection has been interrupted.
        // Disable any UI components that depend on Google APIs
        // until onConnected() is called.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // This callback is important for handling errors that
        // may occur while attempting to connect with Google.
        //
        // More about this in the 'Handle Connection Failures' section.

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mCurrentLocation` will only be a lat/long coordinate set.

You will need to convert these coordinates via "reverse geocoding".

See this doc from Google ("Displaying a Location Address"):
https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

What `Location` gives you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: Maybe you could help me to include the geocode to my app? I have tried, but didn't get it working :(